# What's the appropriate SE site for Yield Managament?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a developer, so my current client would like me to write a system that keeps in mind yield management while doing prices for users.

I'm not that into the math\financial\marketing sector, so I'd like to ask a question about this and get some suggestions.
Where should I ask this in your opinion?

Comment: What kind of questions?

Comment: @Oded about: my client has packages that usually costs X, but he would like to apply a discount price considering time and general demand of these packages. So the question would be about how to generate the formula behind it mainly and about best practices on how to apply that in their opinion\experience.

Comment: There are a few mathematics related Stack Exchange sites, but you would need to read their help center documents to familiarize yourself with their exact scope. Perhaps one of them would be a good place.

Comment: @oded Yes, indeed... I was uncertain about Computative Science and Mathoverflow. I guess that Quantitative Finance might be an overkill and also offtopic.

Comment: I would stay clear from Mathoverflow - that's research grade maths.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I meant Math.SE

Comment: That's a possibility. Not active there, so don't know what their guidelines are like.

Comment: What about CrossValidated?

Comment: That's a statistics site. You can ask on their Meta to see if that kind of question is acceptable.

Comment: Just another bit of advice, yield calculations are normally very basic math (percentages etc) and just about every bean counter has their opinion on how it should be done so there's probably not any good industry guidelines. For a start it might be best to ask them what formulas / spreadsheets etc they have at the moment they like to use.

Comment: So I should rather ask for generic advice on how yield might be better managed speaking of math? @PeterJ

Comment: @XCore was more thinking get the clients ideas first and if you get stuck on some calculations ask on Math.SE or elsewhere. You'll probably find their accountants / management already have some ideas on how it should work and for most industries it can vary so widely it's not embarrasing to ask how they think it should work.

Comment: @PeterJ oh, yeah, we already briefed about this, in fact I already have a "formula draft". But I'm unsure if that might be working.